# How to prove that a depth-first algorithm labels every vertex of G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I understand exactly how a depth-first search/algorithm works. You start at the root, and then go to the left most node, and go down as far as you can until you hit a leaf, and then start going back and hitting the nodes you did not hit before.

I get how it works, and I can see that if a graph is connected than it is going to hit every vertex, but I do not know how to really prove it. It seems as simple that if the graph is connected, then it is going to hit every vertex, but I know it can't be that simple...

Comment: You talk about roots, left-most nodes and leaves, which sounds like the language of plane-oriented trees, but then you talk about connected graphs in general. Which one is it?

Comment: The question asks to prove it labels every vertex, so I'm gonna say graphs. I'm just a computer science guy, so looking at it like that makes it easier for me.

Comment: In a general graph, one usually doesn't have the notion of a left-most node -- so I guess you'd be visiting the neighbours in some arbitrary order?

Comment: Yes. The wording just sounds weird to me, so I use  the terms I learned in CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the search didn't visit all vertices, there is a non-empty set of vertices that it visited and a non-empty set of vertices that it didn't visit. Since the graph is connected, there is at least one edge between a visited vertex and a non-visited vertex. But when the algorithm reached the visited vertex, it successively visited each of its neighbours, each time returning after finitely many steps (since each of the finitely many edges is traversed at most twice), and thus also visited the non-visited vertex. The contradiction shows that all vertices were visited.

Comment: That made it so much easier! Very easy to follow it like this.